# How to optimize sqlite3 in memory database perfomance

Tags: optimization, sqlite

Are there any optimizations that I can apply to `in memory` sqlite3 database? Are there some reasons to change something?

- Must I change "journal_mode" to "memory" or OFF for such
  database?
- Must I periodically do `VACUUM` for memory database?
- Is there any reasons to increase `page_size` ?
- The same question about `PRAGMA schema.synchronous;` and WAL mode.
- Any other suggestions?

Thanks

p.s. I plane to periodically backup (api) this database to disk.

Comment: @RyanVincent The questions is more about sqlite3 documentations and settings. On the sqlite3 website all of them are described for file databases, therefore I have no idea how all of them will effect `in memory' databases.

Comment: @RyanVincent Yes, I'm about `general` discussion/optimizations for sqlite3 memory databases. I.E. seems at such cases it does not need `journal` if our database is already in memory. But I maybe wrong...